# integral on a set A (polar coordinates)

Tags: real-analysis

I have a set $A=\{(x,y)\in R^2: 1 \le x^2+y^2\le 4 \}$ and I want calculate $$\int_A \left({{xe^{x^2+y^2}}\over{x^2+y^2}}-1\right)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$$.

I use polar coordinates $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$.

I obtain $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(\int_{1}^{2}\cos\theta e^{r^2} \mathrm{d}r\right)\mathrm{d}\theta-\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(\int_{1}^{2}r \mathrm{d}r\right)\mathrm{d}\theta.$$
How can I calculate the first integral? It's null?

Comment: Yes it's null. ...just integrate with respect to theta first. $dx dy=r d\theta dr$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the first integral is zero because $$\int_0^{2\pi} \cos(\theta) \, \mathrm{d}\theta = 0$$.

More generally, if we let $$f(x,y) := \frac{x \exp\left(x^2 + y^2\right)}{x^2 + y^2}$$

Then we see that $f$ satisfies $f(x,y) = -f(-x,y)$.

If we let

$$ A_1 = \{ (x,y) \, | \, 1 \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 4, \, x \geq 0 \}, \,\,\, A_2 = \{ (x,y) \, | \, 1 \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 4, \, x \leq 0 \} $$

Then we have

$$\int_A f(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y = \int_{A_1} f(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y + \int_{A_2} f(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y$$

Performing the change of variables $\varphi(u,v) = (-u, v) = (x,y)$ (that is, $x = -u$ and $ y = v$, we see that $\varphi(A_2) = A_1$ and the Jacobian is one so

$$
\begin{align} \int_{A_1} f(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y &= \int_{A_2} f(-u, v) \, \mathrm{d}u \mathrm{d}v\\ &= \int_{A_2} -f(u, v) \, \mathrm{d}u \mathrm{d}v\\ &= -\int_{A_2} f(u, v) \, \mathrm{d}u \mathrm{d}v 
\end{align}
$$

So the integrals cancel out and we have

$$ \int_A f(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y = 0. $$

Comment: so the final result is $-3\pi$?

Comment: Yes, which is the area of the annulus $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea to prove that
$$\int_A\left({{xe^{x^2+y^2}}\over{x^2+y^2}}\right)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y = 0.$$
Apply the [change of variables theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChangeofVariablesTheorem.html) with the transformation
$$T(x,y) = (-x,y).$$