# integral on a set B

Tags: real-analysis

I have a a set $B=B_1\cup B_2$ with $B_1=\{(x,y)\in R^2:x\le0,y\ge0,x^2+y^2\le1\}$ and $B_2=\{(x,y) \in R^2:0\le x\le1,|y|\le|1-x|^3 \}$.

I want calculate $\int_B y\sqrt{x^2+y^2}e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\,dx\,dy$.

For the integral on $B_1$ I can use polar coordiantes but for the second integral? There is a particular simmetry on the domain? $B_2$ is symmetric about x-axis and the function is dispair in variable y so the integral on $B_2$ is null?

Comment: $B_2$ is symmetric about the Y-axis. See my answer in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1595223/integral-on-a-set-a-polar-coordinates/1595247#1595247.

Comment: isn't it  about X-axis?

Comment: Isn't. Can't be with the condition $0\le x\le 1$.

Comment: the final result is ${1 \over 2} - {1 \over e}$?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla It's symmetric about the $X$-axis.

Comment: @Soke, $(1,0)\in B_2$, $(-1,0)\not\in B_2$.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla If $B$ is symmetric about the $x$-axis, that implies $(x, y) \in B \implies (x, -y) \in B$.

Comment: @Soke, you are right, sorry for the mess.

Answer (score 1):

The domains $B_1$ and $B_2$ are disjoint so you can just separate each integral separately.

For $B_1$: Use polar coordinates.

\begin{align}
\int_{B_1} y \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} e^{-(x^2 + y^2)} &= \int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} \int_0^1  e^{-r^2} r^3 \sin \theta \, dr \, d\theta\\
&= \int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} \sin \theta \, d \theta \left| -\frac{1}{2} e^{-r^2} (r^2 + 1) \right|_0^1\\
&= \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{e}
\end{align}

For $B_2$: Consider the function $f(x, y)$ we are integrating over. For fixed $x$, this becomes an odd function in $y$, and since $B_2$ is symmetric about the $x$ axis the integral over $B_2$ is zero.